# Extracting the hyperlink from link tag using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Consider the html as

```
<item>
<title>this is the title</title>
<link>www.linktoawebsite.com</link>
</item>
```

I am using Lxml(python) and Xpath and trying to extract both the content of the title tag as well as the link tag.
The code is

```
page=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
x=etree.HTML(page)
titles=x.xpath('//item/title/text()')
links=x.xpath('//item/link/text()')
```

But this is returning an empty list. However, this is returning a link element.

```
links=x.xpath('//item/link')        #returns <Element link at 0xb6b0ae0c>
```

Can anyone suggest how to extract the urls from the link tag?

Comment: `item` and `link` are not valid HTML elements; why use `etree.HTML` at all here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong parser for the job; you don't have HTML, you have XML.

A proper HTML parser will ignore the contents of a `<link>` tag, because in the HTML specification that tag is always empty.

Use the `etree.parse()` function to parse your URL stream (no separate `.read()` call needed):

```
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
tree = etree.parse(response)

titles = tree.xpath('//item/title/text()')
links = tree.xpath('//item/link/text()')
```

You could also use `etree.fromstring(page)` but leaving the reading to the parser is easier.

Answer (score 1):

By parsing content by `etree`, the  `<link>` tag get closed. So no text value present for link tag

Demo:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> content = """<item>
... <title>this is the title</title>
... <link>www.linktoawebsite.com</link>
... </item>"""
>>> x = etree.HTML(content)
>>> etree.tostring(x)
'<html><body><item>\n<title>this is the title</title>\n<link/>www.linktoawebsite.com\n</item></body></html>'
>>>
```

According to [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp), this is not valid tag.

I think `link` tag structure is like:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Yes you are right about that <link> tag being closed, is there any way to get its content still? @Vivek Sable

Comment: ok, I think all parser are implemented according to HTML rules. I check or go with string processing.

Comment: considering the string as s, then we can use s[s.find('<link/>')+len('<link/>') : s.find('</item>')]. this is basic string slicing.

Comment: yes,\ If you need more help then free to ask questions on stackoverflow or on vivekbsable@gmail.com(my ID)

Comment: @Taranjeet: again, why use `etree.HTML()` here then? You have XML, not HTML.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : so should I use xml parser then. actually I have done most of the work using HTML etree, but still if there is any alternative approach I can try.

Comment: @Taranjeet: the only real difference is how the input is parsed; the rest of the API is the same. Use `etree.parse()` directly on the response, or use `etree.fromstring()` on the bytestring.